# VHDL 2008 and CASE statement

Tags: vhdl, hardware, fpga

I've a question about a case statement and VHDL 2008. I've an entity defined in this way :

```
entity multiplier_v2 is
generic(    WIDTH_WORD  : integer := 32;
            WIDTH_RSA   : integer := 2048;
            LENGTH_ADDRESS : integer := 6 );
port (
    reset                   :   in std_logic;
    clk                     :   in std_logic;
    start                   :   in std_logic;
    input_1                 :   in std_logic_vector(WIDTH_WORD - 1 downto 0);
    input_2                 :   in std_logic_vector(WIDTH_WORD - 1 downto 0);
    module                  :   in std_logic_vector(WIDTH_WORD - 1 downto 0);
    output                  :   out std_logic_vector(WIDTH_WORD - 1 downto 0);
    ack_data                :   out std_logic;
    data_valid              :   out std_logic;
    new_module              :   in std_logic;
```

Inside the module I've a signal declared in this way :

```
signal counter_ack                  : std_logic_vector(LENGTH_ADDRESS - 1 downto 0);
```

I use this signal in a case statement :

```
case counter_ack is
when (others => '1') =>
    ack_data <= '0';
when others => 
    counter_ack <= counter_ack + 1;
end case;
```

Now, I'm pretty sure that VHDL-2008 option is enabled in my synthesis tool but I have the following error regarding that part of my code:

> 2049990 ERROR - E:/My_Designs/Custom Module/Montgomery_Multiplier/Diamond/src/multiplier_v2.vhd(456,6-461,15) (VHDL-1544) array type case expression must be of a locally static subtype

I've read that this error should be fixed in VHDL-2008. Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's legal in VHDL-2008 (even though some tool may accept it) since the range is unconstrained. IMO, You would be better off with "if counter_ack = 2**counter_ack'length-1 then ack_data <= '0'; else counter_ack <= counter_ack + 1; end if;

Comment: @JonathanDrolet Thank for the help. Actually I don't know if it's legal or not. I've seen that in many forum this is a suggested solution. I can use if statement, but it's different in terms of synthesis from a case ( I've several case like that in my source code ). Then I really don't understand where there is the problem. When I place the component in my VHDL source cose, the synthetizer knows the size of the signals. It isn't unconstrained. Then why with the "If"  should be ok and with the "case" doesn't ?  Maybe my fault  is to think as a C programmer.

Comment: VHDL is strongly typed (C is not) and was designed to catch as many errors at compile time as possible. Even though it is quite clear how the code should be interpreted, VHDL ask you to explicitly write it, just in case. Things like implicit type casting exist in C, but not in VHDL. VHDL-2008 softened the pedanticness, but will never remove it. My if code line compares the std_logic_vector (I assumed you used ieee.numeric_std_unsigned) with an integer, which is legal since there is an overloaded compare operator.

Comment: @haster8558, if you use a case statement like this it will produce identical results to an if statement.   You might consider posting more of your code.  How do you reset the counter?  You might consider down counting to 0.

Comment: You might consider constraining the size of the choice.  (LENGTH_ADDRESS -1 downto 0 => '0')

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the code displayed below in Quartus II with VHDL 2008 compiler option. I got no error. Does your case statement is in a process?

```
LIBRARY ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY casestate IS
generic(    WIDTH_WORD  : integer := 32;
            WIDTH_RSA   : integer := 2048;
            LENGTH_ADDRESS : integer := 6 );
port (
    reset                   :   in std_logic;
    clk                     :   in std_logic;
    ack_data                :   out std_logic
     );
END casestate;

ARCHITECTURE fpga OF casestate IS
    signal counter_ack                  : std_logic_vector(LENGTH_ADDRESS - 1 downto 0);

BEGIN

process(clk,reset)
begin
if(reset = '0')then
    ack_data <= '0';
elsif(rising_edge(clk))then
    case counter_ack is
        when (others => '1') =>
            ack_data <= '0';
        when others => 
            counter_ack <= counter_ack + 1;
            ack_data <= '1';
        end case;
end if;
end process;
end fpga;
```

Comment: Yes it is in a process. In my opinion is Diamond ( Lattice Semiconductor IDE) that sucks. I've no error with synplify too. The VHDL-2008 it doesn't handle well. I can choose the synthesis tool  in Diamond ( Synplify or Lattice synthesis tool ). The first work, the second doesn't. Now I guess that if I want to use the Lattice logic analyzer, I mustn't use the VHDL-2008.

Comment: @Nicolas, please don't use the package "std_logic_signed".   What do you propose to do with counter_ack to reset it?  As coded, your design is required to hold counter_ack at its current value during reset.  This will connect your reset signal to functional logic, which could create issues WRT a global reset line.

Comment: @Jim  i wrote this code just for testing if the compiler gives me error. I don't really care about if this code has a sense but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the range, (others => '1') is an unconstrained vector

So you could do something like

when (counter_ack'range => '1') =>

which is a vector of defined length that should work in more software that doesn't make inferences.

this also works for if statements
if VEC = (VEC'range => '0') then
CODE
end if;